# mainMixerNode crash in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm trying code below and I'm using this example http://www.tmroyal.com/playing-sounds-in-swift-audioengine.html

The application crashed when this line.

```
var mixer = engine.mainMixerNode
```

The code like below :

```
var buffer:AVAudioPCMBuffer
var sr:Float

let engine:AVAudioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var player:AVAudioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

var mixer = engine.mainMixerNode

engine.attach(player)

engine.connect(player, to: mixer, format: player.outputFormat(forBus: 0))

buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: player.outputFormat(forBus: 0), frameCapacity: 100)

buffer.frameLength = 100

sr = Float(mixer.outputFormat(forBus: 0).sampleRate)


var i:Int=0

while i < Int(buffer.frameLength) {
    var val = sinf(441.0*Float(i)*2*Float(M_PI) / Float(sr))
    buffer.floatChannelData?.pointee[i] = val * 0.5
    i+=1
}


try! engine.start()

player.play()

player.scheduleBuffer(buffer, at: nil, options: .loops, completionHandler: nil)
```

Is something changed about mainMixerNode in Swift 3? How can I solve that crash?

Comment: Apart from the fact that the `AVAudioEngine` appears to be a local variable and will go out of scope before the audio finishes playing, everything seems fine. I can't imagine why `engine.mainMixerNode` would crash. Can you provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project and I tried this code in the new project.
It works now.